# Initializing instance variable: Idiomatic way

Tags: python

In Python what is the idiomatic way for initializing Python's instance variable:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
```

Or

```
class Test2:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.a = data[0]
        self.b = data[1]
        self.c = data[2]
        self.d = data[3]
```

UPDATE: I have around 20 instance variables for a class named Link:

```
self.street 
self.anode 
self.bnode 
self.length 
self.setbackA 
self.setbackB 
self.bearingA 
self.bearingB 
self.ltype 
self.lanesAB 
self.leftAB 
self.rightAB 
self.speedAB 
self.fspdAB 
self.capacityAB 
self.lanesBA 
self.leftBA 
self.rightBA 
self.speedBA 
self.fspdBA 
self.capacityBA 
self.use
```

Each variable is related to the class `Link`. Is there a recommended way of refactoring this?

Comment: I strongly prefer the first. It is more explicit and allows assignment out of order if you so choose, e.g. `Test(b=4, a=3, d=1, c=1)`

Comment: Also you can still apply an array to the constructor using `Test(*[1, 2, 3, 4])`.

Comment: +1 on Cyber's answer `Test` is much better

Comment: @Cyber I have around 20 instance variables and passing them like that seems to be eye sore. Is that ok even if it is around 20 instance variables ?

Comment: If you have a class that requires 20 variables to instantiate, maybe you could consider refactoring?

Comment: @Sibi - if a method needs 20 variables, it's probably a sign that something's off about your architecture. You should instead either create a custom object/use dictionaries to make it easier to pass data around.

Comment: With 20+ variables (if necessary), you can create a dictionary `cfg = {'a': 1, 'b':2, ...}` and pass it as `Test(**cfg)`.

Comment: @Cyber I have a class named `Link` with various instance variables inside it like `link name`, `link_street_id` etc. Each are unique variables relating to `Link` class. I doubt if that can be refactored.

Comment: Try posting your Link class and any related code on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) -- they can probably help you refactor. If you're right, and it's impossible to refactor your code, they might at least be able to suggest some techniques for making it more manageable and confirm that you're doing things correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpacking an array into a bunch of named variables suggests you should have started with named variables  in the first place - stick with the first one.

There is only one reason you might want the second one here - you have something that is inconsiderately producing lists rather than objects. If that does happen:

```
data = get_data_in_list_form()
actual_data = Test(*data)
```

---

Can you group some of your data:

```
self.street
self.ltype
self.use
self.length

# .a and .b can be instances of NodeConnection
self.a.setback
self.a.bearing

self.b.setback
self.b.bearing
self.b.node

# .ab and .ba can be a separate class, "UniDirectionalLink
self.ab.lanes
self.ab.left
self.ab.right
self.ab.speed
self.ab.fspd
self.ab.capacity

self.ba.lanes
self.ba.left
self.ba.right
self.ba.speed
self.ba.fspd
self.ba.capacity
```

There's no need to do everything in a constructor here:

```
link = (
    Link(street=..., ltype=..., use=..., length=...)
        .starting_at(node_a, bearing=..., setback=...)
        .finishing_at(node_b, bearing=..., setback=...)
        .forward_route(lanes, left, right, speed, fspd, capacity)
        .reverse_route(lanes, left, right, speed, fspd, capacity)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added some more details to the question.

Answer (score 4):

The former, since it's more explicit about what the parameters are and what the object requires.

If you *do* need to pass in your data as a tuple, there's a shortcut you can use. Instead of doing the latter, or something like:

```
test = Test(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3])
```

You can instead unpack the list/tuple and do:

```
test = Test(*data)
```

If you need to pass in a bunch of data (more then 4-5), you should look into either using optional/keyword arguments, creating a custom object to hold some of the data, or using a dictionary:

```
config = Config(a, b, c, d)
test = Test(e, f, config, foo=13, bar=True)
```

---

I would probably refactor your Link class to look like this:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, node, setback, bearing):
        self.node = node
        self.setback = setback 
        self.bearing = bearing 

class Connection(object):
    def __init__(self, lanes, left, right, speed, fspd, capacity):
        self.lanes = lanes 
        self.left = left 
        self.right = right 
        self.speed = speed 
        self.fspd = fspd 
        self.capacity = capacity 

class Link(object):
    def __init__(self, street, length, ltype, use, a, b, ab, ba):
        self.street = street 
        self.length = length 
        self.ltype = ltype 
        self.use = use 

        self.a = a 
        self.b = b 
        self.ab = ab 
        self.ba = ba
```

I saw that you had some duplicate data, so pulled those off into a separate object. While this doesn't reduce on the number of fields you have, overall, it does make the parameters you need to pass in smaller.

Having a large number of fields isn't bad, but having a large number of parameters generally is. If you can write your methods in a way that they don't need a huge amount of parameters by bundling together data, then it doesn't really matter how many fields you have.

Comment: Thanks, I have added some more details to the question.

Comment: @Sibi -- could you explain a little more on what 'AB' and 'BA' means?

Comment: AB means from A to B direction and B to A is the opposite direction. They may not necessarily have the same values.